# Did the services at USCIS for UK visa resumed?

Tags: uk

I cant find this information anywhere. please help

Comment: Yes, over a month ago.

Comment: Perfect! Is it updated anywhere? I cant find the information online.

Comment: It was last month, and then the news was so old they took it down.